# Django 'no such column' after changing spelling of attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have the following classes:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='restaurant')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='restaurant_logo/', blank=False)

class RestaurantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ("name", "phone", "address", "logo")
```

I realized I spelled address as "adress" so i changed it to "address". Now I get the error 'no such column'. I tried making migrations but it says 'No changes detected'. How can I fix this?

Comment: If it's early in your project (development stage), you could perhaps purge the database tables and start anew.

Comment: Otherwise, you'll probably have to manually edit the (or create a new) migration file, using the [`https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#alterfield`[(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#alterfield) class. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As @00 suggested I just deleted the database folder and than the migration commands again. And it worked!